# Making an empty list within a function and passing it to global scope. (initialising empty list in function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I want to make a function that takes makes a list and adds an item to that list when I run it, so basically I would be passing this function two arguments, the first is the name I want the list to have, the second is an item I want to add to the list. 
I want to do this as a learning excercise and I've built a function that almost does what I want it to do.

```
def addlst(l, item):
        """add an item to a list"""
        l = list()#this line essentially does nothing. 
        if type(item) == str:    
            l.append(item.capitalize())
            return l
            print(l)
        else:
            l.append(item)
            return l
            print(l)
```

if I pass this something like:

```
addlst(people, 'kev')
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'people' is not defined
```

but obviously, if I define people as an empty list it works fine.

Is what I'm doing actually possible? I know that as it stands the line

```
l = list()
```

would just empty the list first and so the append function would be useless (I'd have to add another clause to check if the list exists already) but my question is really about initialising a blank list within a function and then returning it to the global scope.

Comment: Simply type `global l` within your function definition and `l` will be available globally.

Comment: Thanks a million, but when I add that I get 
    SyntaxError: name 'l' is parameter and global

Comment: This is because you declare `l` both as an argument of your function as well as a global variable, hence the error you get. See my answer.

Comment: `addList` itself cannot (easily) and should not create a new name in the calling scope. The first argument has to be an existing list.

Comment: I generally agree with @chepner, but feel it's a poor programming practice to _ever_ create variables dynamically (regardless of their scope).

Comment: I'm sure it is poor practice, I started coding 2 weeks ago and I'm an idiot. I've been practising making lists, then dicts then dataframes and then playing with the dfs, I just wanted a function to make a list and add stuff to it quickly.

Comment: The *right* thing to do is *return* a list, letting the *caller* assign the return value to whatever name they want. A second optional argument (as shown in [olinox14's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713301/1126841) can be an existing list to return (after appending to it) instead of creating a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: a function should never inject a new name into the calling scope.

1. If the function works with a global variable, that needs to be documented and the caller has to ensure the global exists before calling it.
2. If the function takes an argument, there are two options. One, you can mutate it and have your function return `None`, or you can create a *new* value based on the argument and return that, leaving the argument unchanged. Very rarely, if ever, should your function modify an argument *and* return a value.
3. If you have your function return a new list, you can *optionally* take a list to modify, or create a brand new list inside your function.

Unrelated, but you shouldn't care what the type of `item` is, only that it is something that has a `capitalize` method that you can call. Just try it; if it doesn't, it will raise an `AttributeError` that you can catch, in which case you can simply use `item` as is.

---

Putting all this together, I recommend the third approach. `add_to_list` will take an item as the first argument, and an optional list as the second argument. If no list is given, the function will create a new list. In either case, you'll append the appropriately modified item to the list and return it.

```
def add_to_list(item, l=None):
    # Note: this doesn't change the item you pass; it just rebinds
    # the local name item to a *new* string if it succeeds.
    try:
        item = item.capitalize()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    if l is None:
        l = []

    return l + [item]
```

Then you can use

```
people = add_to_list('kev')  # people == ['Kev']
people = add_to_list('bob')  # people == ['Bob'], Kev is gone!
people = add_to_list('kev', people)  # people == ['Bob', 'Kev'], Kev is back.
```

---

The more efficient version mentioned in the second approach modifies `l` in place; in this case, though, you *have* to provide a list; you can't create a new list.

```
def add_to_list(item, l):
    try:
        item = item.capitalize()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    l.append(item)

people = []  # Create the list in the *calling* scope, not in add_to_list
add_to_list('kev')  # TypeError, missing an argument
add_to_list('kev', people)  # people == ['Kev']
add_to_list('bob', people)  # people == ['Kev', 'Bob']
```

---

The first approach is pretty poor; it restricts your function to working with a specific list whose name is hard-coded in the function, but I'll mention it here for completeness. Since the list is hard-coded, we'll change the name of the function to reflect that.

```
def add_to_people(item):
    global people

    try:
        item = item.capitalize()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    people.append(item)
```

Now `add_to_list` can work with the global list `people`, but no other list.

```
people = []
add_to_people('kev')
add_to_people('bob')
```

---

And finally, in the interest of full disclosure, yes, `add_to_people` can create the list if it hasn't already:

```
def add_to_people(item):
    global people

    try:
        people  # Simply try to evaluate the name
    except NameError:
        people = []

    # ...
```

However, if using a global name in the first place is bad, autovivifying it like this is worse. Avoid this style of programming wherever possible.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm going to try to pick through all of this and really try to understand each of the options. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

*Putting aside the discussion regarding whether it is a good practice*, (which can make sens if your main goal is about improving your understanding), you could simply use the [global keyword](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword) to do what you describe. Say

```
def f(el):
    global l
    l.append(el)
```

Then

```
>>> l = []
>>> f(2)
>>> l
[2]
>>> f(3)
>>> l
[2, 3]
```

As it reads above, `l` has to be declared before using `f`.

---

Dealing with your peculiarities, something you could do is:

```
def addlst(item):
    """add an item to a list"""
    global l#
    if isinstance(item, str):     # type(item) == str is not recommanded
        item = item.capitalize()
    l.append(item)
```

But actually, note that doing so will "bind" your function to deal exclusively with the list named `l` in the global scope. And it looks like this is not what you want, since it appears that you want to be able to pass multiple list objects to your function. The best approach here is

```
def addlst(list_, item):
    """add an item to a list"""
    if isinstance(item, str):
        item = item.capitalize()
    list_.append(item)
    return list_
```

Comment: Is it not the case that I still have to initialize l outside the function though?

Comment: @KevOMalley743 Yes. If you do `f(2)` without having first declared `l = []`, you will get an error;

Comment: Thanks a million for taking the time.

Comment: @martineau Actually, I was surprised of not being downvoted earlier :)

Comment: Plus, correct me if I'm wrong but you don't even need the `global` statement to append an item to a list... your `f()` method should work without it.

Comment: Correct; `global` is only need to *assign* to non-local names.  An assignment immediately makes a name refer to a local variable. Absent an assignment, the name is a free variable that refers to a non-local variable (which is usually a global, but may also be a local variable in another function if the the current function is a closure).

Comment: @olinox14 Yes you are right. But only because `l` is mutable.

Comment: @keepAlive Mutability is irrelevant; the name `l` still refers to the global variable in the absence of a local variable named `l`, whether that variable refers to a mutable object or not.

Comment: @chepner try to change the value of an integer within a local scope, that also exists globally, but without having first declared it using the word global.... Does it work? no.

Comment: @keepAlive That's an entirely different scenario. You've got a local variable that shadows a global, and you are actually trying to change the object the name refers to, not mutating the existing object.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `addlst(people, 'kev')`, you're telling your code that you want to execute the `addlst` function with a **variable** named `people` as first parameter.

**Problem is**: you never set this variable!

There are many ways to this; You could either initialize an empty list before calling the function:

```
people = []
addlst(people, 'kev')
```

Or make the parameter optional with a default value:

```
 def addlst(item, l = None):
   """add an item to a list"""
    if l is None:
        l = []
    if type(item) == str:    
        l.append(item.capitalize())
        return l
    else:
        l.append(item)
        return l
```

But that could be tricky, since lists are [mutable objects](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/).

> NB: In your function, `print` will never be called because it stands after the `return` statement.

#### A last way

Eventually, you could also shorten your code by doing something like that:

```
mylist = []
item = "test"
mylist.append(item.capitalize() if type(item) == str else item)
```

Comment: Not a very good idea to use a mutable as default value. :) I mean, doing `def addlst(.... l = [])`.

Comment: `l = []` is just wrong. You need to use `None` as the default, and assign `l = []` inside the function to get a *new* empty list for each call.

Comment: `type(item) == str` is also wrong; use `isinstance(item, str)` to accommodate any potential subclass of `str` that might arise.

Comment: @keepalive: I already precised it, see after the 'optional parameter' solution :)

Comment: @chepner About the use of type or isinstance, you are right but that was not the subject of the question. `type() == str` perfectly does the job here.

Comment: @olinox14 Yes you did! mea culpa.

Comment: @chepner And you're right about the way of passing the optional parameter, my bad: I'll correct it.

Comment: @olinox14 You can fix bad practices in the original code, even if they are not directly related to the question. Strive to provide a good example in your answers.

Comment: @chepner I usually do that, but in that case I don't agree: `isinstance` do not have the same behaviour that `type() == item`. What if I do not want subclasses to be capitalized? For example a `Path` object from the path.py lib?

Comment: I was about to post another comment or answer (hadn't decided which yet), which points out that you really don't care *what* type `item` has, as long as it has a `capitalize` method. The right thing to do is try to call it, and catch the resulting `AttributeError`.

Comment: @chepner Of course, classic case of 'ask forgiveness not permission', but again, you're assuming that you want subclasses to be capitalized.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? An instance of a subclass is still a `str`; you are violating encapsulation if you start trying to bypass it.